# JS: How to test a escape function for regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex, unit-testing, mocha.js

I am using this escape function for regular expression:

```
escapeRegExp = (str) => {
    return String(str).replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, '\\$1')
}
```

Now I would like to write a simple test for this function. So I came up with this:

```
it('escapes a regular expression string', () => {
    const   input = '/path/to/resource.html?search=query',
            result = '\\/path\\/to\\/resource\\.html\\?search\\=query'

    expect(escapeRegExp(input)).to.equal(result)
})
```

But this won't cover all escaping options, which is included in the function.

How can I get a better test for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is are a fair few implementations of this method in different libraries.

Here is one such library: https://github.com/ljharb/regexp.escape

If you need to test your own, then testing all scenarios will take a fair amount of tests - as the function exists, people must have already written tests for it - for example prototype has the following tests:

```
assert.equal('word', RegExp.escape('word'));
assert.equal('\\/slashes\\/', RegExp.escape('/slashes/'));
assert.equal('\\\\backslashes\\\\', RegExp.escape('\\backslashes\\'));
assert.equal('\\\\border of word', RegExp.escape('\\border of word'));

assert.equal('\\(\\?\\:non-capturing\\)', RegExp.escape('(?:non-capturing)'));
assert.equal('non-capturing', new RegExp(RegExp.escape('(?:') + '([^)]+)').exec('(?:non-capturing)')[1]);

assert.equal('\\(\\?\\=positive-lookahead\\)', RegExp.escape('(?=positive-lookahead)'));
assert.equal('positive-lookahead', new RegExp(RegExp.escape('(?=') + '([^)]+)').exec('(?=positive-lookahead)')[1]);

assert.equal('\\(\\?<\\=positive-lookbehind\\)', RegExp.escape('(?<=positive-lookbehind)'));
assert.equal('positive-lookbehind', new RegExp(RegExp.escape('(?<=') + '([^)]+)').exec('(?<=positive-lookbehind)')[1]);

assert.equal('\\(\\?\\!negative-lookahead\\)', RegExp.escape('(?!negative-lookahead)'));
assert.equal('negative-lookahead', new RegExp(RegExp.escape('(?!') + '([^)]+)').exec('(?!negative-lookahead)')[1]);

assert.equal('\\(\\?<\\!negative-lookbehind\\)', RegExp.escape('(?<!negative-lookbehind)'));
assert.equal('negative-lookbehind', new RegExp(RegExp.escape('(?<!') + '([^)]+)').exec('(?<!negative-lookbehind)')[1]);

assert.equal('\\[\\\\w\\]\\+', RegExp.escape('[\\w]+'));
assert.equal('character class', new RegExp(RegExp.escape('[') + '([^\\]]+)').exec('[character class]')[1]);

assert.equal('<div>', new RegExp(RegExp.escape('<div>')).exec('<td><div></td>')[0]);

assert.equal('false', RegExp.escape(false));
assert.equal('undefined', RegExp.escape());
assert.equal('null', RegExp.escape(null));
assert.equal('42', RegExp.escape(42));

assert.equal('\\\\n\\\\r\\\\t', RegExp.escape('\\n\\r\\t'));
assert.equal('\n\r\t', RegExp.escape('\n\r\t'));
assert.equal('\\{5,2\\}', RegExp.escape('{5,2}'));

assert.equal(
    '\\/\\(\\[\\.\\*\\+\\?\\^\\=\\!\\:\\$\\{\\}\\(\\)\\|\\[\\\\\\]\\\\\\\/\\\\\\\\\\]\\)\\/g',
    RegExp.escape('/([.*+?^=!:${}()|[\\]\\/\\\\])/g')
);h
```

> https://github.com/sstephenson/prototype/blob/master/test/unit/tests/regexp.test.js

There is an ES7 Proposal to standardise this method: https://github.com/benjamingr/RegExp.escape

Comment: RegExp.escape is only a proposal for ES7, isn't it?

Comment: @user3142695 yes good point I will correct my answer, however in terms of testing the wheel has been built.